# Is there a way to have CSS animation when someone leaves said page?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So i have this css animation already for when someone enters the said page. But is there a way I can reverse the animation or call a new animation when someone leaves.

```
  .clean {
    content: url(/HPA/Clean.svg);
    width: 81%;
    margin-top: 39.5%;
    left: 120%;
    position: absolute;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: ease-in ;
  }

  @keyframes s{

    to {
      width: 81%;
      margin-left: -110.3%;
    }

  }
```

That is the code I have now and I'm just calling out in the HTML with a class callout.
But As stated above can I have an animation play when the person leaves the page?

Comment: You can't do this directly.  The best you can do is add some JavaScript to handle when links are clicked, cancel the default event, change classes or something on your page to trigger the animation, and then proceed navigating afterward.  I'd recommend *not* doing this.

Comment: why would you recommend not doing this?

Comment: Suppose you animate your exit, but then the page you're linking to never actually loads, or takes a long time to load.  Now you're stuck with the exit animation and don't really have any way to recover.  Suppose you animate to the next page, and the user clicks 'back' quickly... the browser may keep the context and now you have already animated out.  If anything, you're just slowing down the user.  It's not a good practice.

Comment: then what's the best way to add page transitions I'm messing around with swup right now

Comment: There isn't one, is what I'm telling you.  Unless of course you're just doing animations for pages internal to your own site, and then it's possible.